# CSS animation problem at last frame on iOS

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm using an animation to bounce an element 2 times to the left.
Everything works fine so far but on iOS the end of the animation isn't smooth anymore.
It jumps from the state on the left to it's normal position. Without animation.
Is there anything I've missed?

Here's my code:

```css
@keyframes bounceright {
0%   {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px); transform:translateX(0px);}
50%  {-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px); transform:translateX(-20px);}
100%  {-webkit-transform:translateX(1px); transform:translateX(1px);}
}

.bounceright {
 -webkit-animation-name: bounceright;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
 animation-name: bounceright;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-iteration-count: 2;
    transition: all 300ms ease 0s;}
```

```html
<div class="bounceright">
 <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, se </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation resetting to its initial state is the default behaviour, to make your animation assume its final state, you can set its **fill mode** to **forwards** like so

```
.bounceright {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Add this */
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceright;    
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;     
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;   
    animation-name: bounceright;    
    animation-duration: 1s;     
    animation-iteration-count: 2; 
    transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `animation-direction`, you can learn more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

Comment: thanks, now everything is smooth but iOS is always one iteration less than desktop... Strange